# video with multiple audio track using video js not working

Tags: javascript, html

im using videojs library where is a player who display the video. the problem is im not able to track the audio after passing the dual audio video there. still im getting track zero. here is my code

```js
const player = videojs('something');

function changeAudio() {
  console.log(player, "all")
  const audioTracks = player.audioTracks();
  console.log(audioTracks, "audioTracks")

  if (audioTracks.length > 1) {
    const currentTrackIndex = player.audioTracks().selectedIndex;
    const nextTrackIndex = (currentTrackIndex + 1) % audioTracks.length;

    audioTracks[nextTrackIndex].enabled = true;
    audioTracks[currentTrackIndex].enabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test2023</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.15.4/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.15.4/video.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  
  <video id="something" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <button onclick="changeAudio()">Change Audio Track</button>
</body>
```

there is button called change audio track on that click my dual audio supported video should change the audio .

Comment: I don't see the documentation suggesting anywhere that AudioTrackList had a `selectedIndex` property?

Comment: this is the documentation https://docs.videojs.com/ and yes AudtioTrackList have selectedIndex properties

Comment: @mohammadsarvar could you point where it says so, because I'm having trouble finding it as well.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Yes here it is https://videojs.com/guides/audio-tracks/

Comment: @CBroe https://videojs.com/guides/audio-tracks/

Comment: I'm still not seeing the `selectedIndex` property on the `AudioTrackList` object. Are you sure it's there?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier yes there only you have to use const audioTracks = player.audioTracks();
      console.log(audioTracks, "audioTracks") here it is i make it short <video id="something" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="http://localhost:4700/video" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <button onclick="changeAudio()">Change Audio Track</button> const player = videojs('something'); const audioTracks = player.audioTracks();
      console.log(audioTracks, "audioTracks")

Comment: Still, I'm not seeing it in your last comment. Though, I did found out that [`AudioTrackList`](https://docs.videojs.com/audiotracklist#members) *doesn't* have the property, but [`VideoTrackList`](https://docs.videojs.com/videotracklist) does. Maybe that is of any help. If you could fix your code snippet then we'd be able the check the property out for ourselfs.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier ok i have updated the code snippet where my player is working now you can debug the properties.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier got any solution yet. ?

Comment: Not really. I'm not able to replicate multiple audio tracks on a video. The video you've included was hosted locally. Please provide a video an the audio tracks that go with it in the snippet above.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier you can try this one as well https://rainwat.nyc3.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/lalocon/nefli/Bliss.mkv this is hosted and have multiple audio file also i found a solution like only streaming file type format can have multiple audio changing facilities over browser but im not sure of it.